# Проблема с глобальной переменной $db

Tags: php

Всем привет , решил я сделать создание аккаунт через классы (через её функции) , тут я столкнулся с такой проблемой что моя $db находит мой класс , проблема была в видимости $db , сделал я её глобальной и тут вылезла такая ошибка :

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ';' or ',' in C:\MAMP\htdocs\exmp1\function.php on line 6**

Сама база данных

```
 try {
  global $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=firstdatabase", 'root', 'root');
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Сам класс с функцией создания аккаунта

```
class User {

  public static function AddUser($login, $password) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (login, password) VALUES (:login, :password)";
    $statment = $db->prepare($sql);

    $statment->bindParam(":login", $login);
    $statment->bindParam(":password", $password);
    $statment->execute();
  }
}
```

Как решить данную проблему ? Заранее спасибо всем кто ответил )

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global

Comment: надо сначала написать global $db; а потом $db = new PDO(...);

Comment: пробовал так-же тоже не заработала

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такой старый [анекдот](https://www.anekdot.ru/id/340624/).

Вот тебе тоже надо определиться - или "через классы", или "с глобальной переменной".

Судя по всему, что такое классы ты не понимаешь от слова "совсем". Но если прямо очень хочется, чтобы всё было как у взрослых, то про глобальные переменные надо вообще навсегда забыть. А $db надо **передавать в конструктор и присваивать свойству класса**:

```
<?php
class User {

    private $db;

    /* Get database access */
    public function __construct(\PDO $pdo) {
        $this->db = $pdo;
    }

    public function AddUser($login, $password) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (login, password) VALUES (:login, :password)";
        $statment = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statment->bindParam(":login", $login);
        $statment->bindParam(":password", $password);
        $statment->execute();
    }
}
```

И соответственно, в коде

```
$user = new User($db);
$user->AddUser($login, $password);
```

В общем все как написано [в этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43631201/285587)

Если же это все пока для тебя слишком сложно, то не надо мучать классы - пиши функциями и инклюдами.

Да, и код соединения тоже неправильный. Соединяться надо так как написано [здесь](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql)

Comment: только тогда метод надо сделать не статическим

Comment: а где в таком случаи делать подключение к базе данных ?

Comment: положить в файл и инклюдить в самом начале

Comment: @HTMLProgrammer спасибо, не заметил

Comment: Понимаю , получается конструкт через сам PDO автоматически находит переменную через которую идет подключение к базе данных , верно ли я говорю ?

 public function __construct(\PDO $pdo) если не сложно объясните пожалуйста для чего \ слеш перед PDO

Comment: Нет, конструктор сам ничего не находит. слеш это пространство имён. Узнаешь, когда будешь учить классы.